# Is 'I am glad to hear that' very formal or informal phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, formality

I responded this to one professor when she expressed about her current research work. Later, I realized that that phrase could be very informal.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

> I am glad to hear that

is not particularly informal or formal. It is probably used more often by polite, well educated people than by others, so I don't think that you need to worry about having said the wrong thing.